# Is it necessary to sanitize a PHP form submit button?

Tags: php

I have had this question for a while. when I use

`$postSubmit = htmlentities($_POST['postSubmit'] ?? null, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

The submit value seems to change and doesn't run the if statement on page load (right after submit). `if(isset($postSubmit))...`

`$postSubmit = $_POST['postSubmit'] ?? null;`

The form is submitted and the value remains "submit" therefore the remaining of the if statement is executed.

Thank you

Comment: You only need to html-encode an input value if you're just about to output it into a html document. Otherwise, no, there is no need.

Comment: htmlentities expects a string for the first parameter, giving it null might throw a type error, too. (but as @ADyson commented, you don't need htmlentities for input processing, you need it for the output [it is good to differ between input and output, e.g. input processing output (IPO) model])

Comment: There's zero security woes from evaluating input data in boolean context (like an `if` expression).

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for the response.